# Unable to display parsed JSON data into UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am parsing JSON data into a model object nested structure. I am also sorting the model and appending to my sortedArr array which is sorted alphabetically. I am attempting to display the names and other information such as biography into my table view. When trying to display the names of the indexPath into my table view cell I am unable to reach the members of the array, such as fullName, biography, etc.

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    struct Students: Decodable {
        var fullName :String
        var biography:String
        var emailAddress:String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case fullName = "full_name"
            case biography
            case emailAddress = "email_address"
        }
    }

    var students:[Students]
}

var sortedArr = [[Response.Students]]()

func parseData(){
    guard let url = URL(string: "xxxxxx") else {return}
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
            return 
        }
        do {
            let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: dataResponse)

             self.sortedArr = response.students.sorted{$0.fullName < $1.fullName}

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sortedArr.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! EmployeeTableViewCell

    let emps = sortedArr[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = emps.fullName  //has no member fullName
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why is `sortedArr` declared as `[Any]` (`Any` is *I don't care*)? Do care because you are supposed to know that the type is more specific and that knowledge will solve your issue by the way.

Comment: when i set it to String i get an error  " Cannot convert value of type '[Response.Students]' to expected argument type 'String' " on  self.sortedArr.append(sortedArray)

Comment: Please read the error (and notice the type of `students`). You have to declare `sortedArr` as `[Response.Students] `. Types are crucial in Swift and if you *don't care* you get those errors.

Comment: is my syntax incorrect to get the fullName property inside of the cell?

Comment: Yes, it is. As I wrote it's `var sortedArr = [Response.Students]()`

Comment: it still says has no member in cellForRowAt and also if I dont put double brackets [[Response.Students]] i get "Cannot convert value of type '[Response.Students]' to expected argument type 'Response.Students' " on self.sortedArr.append(sortedArray)

Comment: Write `self.sortedArr = response.students.sorted{$0.fullName < $1.fullName}` and you should reload the table view on the main thread.